# jquery stop mouseover event after click event

Tags: jquery, event-handling, click, mouseover, mouseout

can someone help me with this

I am trying to set a different color for the element from the click event.

The problem is that the mouseover event makes everything white again. So, I will never 
get to see the color off the active(actief)class.

What could I do, I already try'd putting in the line stopevent propagation()??

thanks, Richard

```
$("#tbestel_opties2 span").live("mouseover", function() {
            $t=$(this);
            if(!$t.hasClass('actief')){

                $t.css({'color':'#fff','backgroundColor':'#fdc601'}); 
            }
        });
        $("#tbestel_opties2 span").live("mouseout", function() {
                $t=$(this);
                if(!$t.hasClass('actief')){
                $t.css({'color':'#333','backgroundColor':'#fdc601'});                                                                          }
        });

        $("#tbestel_opties input,#tbestel_opties2 span").live("click", function(e)
        {e.stopPropagation(); 
            $t=$(this);
              $('#tbestel_opties2 .actief').removeClass("actief").css({'color':'#333'});

             $t.addClass("actief")

            $("#opties li:eq(0)").addClass("actief");


    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class instead. When an element is clicked, add another class to the element. Make sure this class is not set before you do anything in mouseover/out. This also has the advantage of allowing you to move the styling of the clicked elements into your CSS if you wish.

Comment: Thanks, so just use addClass and NOT the css(). I will try that. Although I don't understand why hasClass diddn't work?

Answer (score 1):

That stop propagation function stops the default behavior of the click event and has no bearing on the mouseover.

Changing your use of the css selector to an addClass function that corresponds with those CSS changes, you'll be able to get the order of events you're looking for.

Comment: Looks like Dark Falcon beat me by a minute on classes ;)

Comment: It gets frustrating sometimes typing out an answer then seeing someone post the exact same answer just seconds before. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this in your mouseover event:

```
var currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
jQuery.data($(this).get(0), "basecolor", currentColor);
```

it stores metadata with the element. you could then read that value in the click event

```
var currentColor = jQuery.data($(this).get(0), "basecolor");
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to rain on the JQuery parade, but why not just use the :hover psuedo class?

Comment: It seems you're seriously overthinking things. I didn't mean add a hover class with Jquery, I meant add an element with a class, and have .class:hover defined on your style sheets... You are using javascript to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: :hover is not supported on anything but the 'a' tag in IE6. If he requires what I now can thankfully consider legacy support, your solution will not work as it appears he is targeting a span tag.